# Why does Lightroom (5) take longer to import a single image if a folder contains more images?

Tags: lightroom-5, performance

If I have images on a hard drive, and one folder has 5-10 images, importing a *single* image (RAW) is very fast. Yet if a folder has 50 images, it takes Much longer to import that same image. In fact it seems the import time increase is directly proportional, and can take extremely long if there are many images. I'm reluctant to upgrade to the newer versions of LR, because often there is a performance sacrifice with each new version. Is this a known issue and is there a solution? Thanks

Comment: I've never noticed that specific issue, but there's a bit of good news that Adobe [just released](http://blogs.adobe.com/lightroomjournal/2017/07/on-lightroom-performance.html). I'd definitely go to [this page](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/LrDesktop_performance) and fill out the survey.

Comment: Nah, that's just a survey...it's too general. I could do a detailed report with *reproducible* issues/bugs. I wish they focused on efficiency rather than.. well I'm not sure what. Version 3.6 was much more efficient than subsequent ones. Noise reduction was improved a bit in later versions, but mostly it was about rearranging things. Unfortunately, unlike Photoshop, Lightroom doesn't use camera raw plugins, and if you have an unsupported camera you have to upgrade the whole Lightroom every time.

Comment: Have you submitted it on this [page](http://www.adobe.com/products/wishform.html)?

Comment: Well that's the thing see. They may fix some things, but introduce new problems in the new version. And the new version requires more resources. And then it's "understood" that you should get a faster computer. Judging from how many times Flash needs to update its security holes, I don't think Adobe pays much to its developers. As a programmer myself I can tell a quality software from... well less so. You take Native Instruments for example, or Autodesk. You know some actions are more resource-intense than others. They way they're handled is how you can tell the quality.